# $.getJson action call not mapping object field

Tags: jquery, jsp, struts2, ognl, struts2-jquery

I have a jsp view file named example.jsp and when click a button, below jquery method invoked :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#a_button").click(function() {
       var json_model== {
                   field1 : $("#a_textarea1").val(),
                   field2 : $("#a_textarea2").val(),
                   field3 : $("#a_textarea3").val(),
        };
       $.getJSON('AnAction', {
           model : json_model
       }, function(jsonResponse) {
           alert('jsonResponse here');
       });
   });
});
```

And here my action class :

```
public class ActionClass implements Action {

private Model model;

@Override
public String execute() throws Exception {return null;}

public String actionMethod() {
    System.out.println("Its Here");
    System.out.println(model.getField1()+" "+model.getField2()+" "+model.getField3()+" ");
    return SUCCESS;
}


public Model getModel() {
    return model;
}

public void setModel(Model model) {
    this.model = model;
}

}
```

And here Model class :

```
public class Model {

private String field1;
private String field2;
private String field3;

public Model(String field1,String field2, String field3) {
    super();
    this.field1 = field1;
    this.field2 = field2;
    this.field3 = field3;
}

public String getField1() {
    return field1;
}
public void setField1(String field1) {
    this.field1 = field1;
}
public String getField2() {
    return field2;
}
public void setResult(String field2) {
    this.field2 = field2;
}
public String getField3() {
    return field3;
}
public void setField3(String field3) {
    this.field3 = field3;
}

}
```

My struts.xml :

```
<action name="AnAction" class="controller.ActionClass" method="actionMethod">
     <result type="json">/example.jsp</result>
 </action>
```

When I click the button, my action call works and I see **Its Here** text on server side console. But action call does not map the Model object.I mean 'model' is null when action invoked. However when I move field1,field2 and field3 to ActionClass like below this works. But of course I want only model object inside Action Class. How can I do that. Thanks for all advices.

```
//THIS IS WORKED VERSION OF ACTION CLASS
public class ActionClass implements Action {

private String field1;
private String field2;
private String field3;

@Override
public String execute() throws Exception {return null;}

public String actionMethod() {
    System.out.println("Its Here");
    System.out.println(field1+" "+field2+" "+field3+" ");
    return SUCCESS;
}


public String getField1() {
    return field1;
}
public void setField1(String field1) {
    this.field1 = field1;
}
public String getField2() {
    return field2;
}
public void setResult(String field2) {
    this.field2 = field2;
}
public String getField3() {
    return field3;
}
public void setField3(String field3) {
    this.field3 = field3;
}

}


//AND MY JQUERY METHOD WHICH IS COMPATIBLE WITH ABOVE
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#a_button").click(function() {

       $.getJSON('AnAction', {
           field1 : $("#a_textarea1").val(),
               field2 : $("#a_textarea2").val(),
               field3 : $("#a_textarea3").val()
       }, function(jsonResponse) {
           alert('jsonResponse here');
       });
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use parameter names prefixed with `model.`

```
var json_model = {
   "model.field1" : $("#a_textarea1").val(),
   "model.field2" : $("#a_textarea2").val(),
   "model.field3" : $("#a_textarea3").val(),
};
$.getJSON('AnAction', json_model, function(jsonResponse) {
       alert('jsonResponse here');
   });
```

The model also needs a default constructor,

```
public Model() {}
```

so you can instantiate it to the action

```
private Model model = new Model();
```

After these changes the `params` interceptor would be able to populate the `model` object with the help of OGNL. And because your model properties are only strings they would be set without any possible type conversion of the parameters.

Comment: Thank you for response, But i dont understand where I should instantiate model object in action ?

Comment: I have instantiated it inline in this answer, where you defined your property in the action class.

Comment: @SedatKURT I said you *can* instantiate it yourself or *can* use DI. If you didn't OGNL null handler will do it, but if creating null objects is enabled. Lucky you have provided a public setter that corresponds to the getter. So, making your action mutable against a model. Also making properties public discourage a java encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Roman C. With A few changes on his response,it WORKS !
My differences from Roman C's response are only:

1) I dont instantiate the model object in action class.
2) I change all 'private' access modifier to 'public' (Otherwise, OGNL has problem with it)